# Json returns every character as a separate object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have a json object that I'm loading from wordpress using the JSON API plugin. When I load the json object and try to log out the parts of it, it seems like it treats every single character as its own object so the loop returns me a couple thousand objects all with item in it which is a single character. This is my first time using json so idk if i'm missing a step here. this is the code I'm using so far.

```
function getProjInfo(theId){ 
    $.ajax({// calling the ajax object of jquery
        type: "GET",// we are going to be getting info from this data source
        url: 'http://testing.charter21.com/api/get_post/?post_id='+ theId,//the datasource
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
        parseJson(data);
    }, // what happens when it is successful at loading the XML 
    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }   
    });

}//end of the function

function parseJson(inData){
    postInfo = inData;
    $.each(postInfo, function(index, value){
    console.log(this);
});

}
```

the json looks like this:
  `{`
 `"status": "ok",`
 `"count": 10,`
`"count_total": 19,`
 `"pages": 2,`
`"posts": [`
    `{`
     `"id": 175,`
     `"type": "post",`
    `"slug": "home-page-slider",`
      `"url": "http:\/\/testing.charter21.com\/uncategorized\/home-page-slider\/",`
     `"status": "publish",`
     `"title": "Home Page slider",`
      `"title_plain": "Home Page slider",`
     `"content": "<p>The cImages in here are the images that are in the slider on the home page this content in this box will not show up. Its only here as a guide.<\/p>\n",`
     `"excerpt": "The cImages in here are the images that are in the slider on the home page this content in this box will not show up. Its only here as a guide.",`
     `"date": "2011-01-25 10:40:25",`
      `"modified": "2011-01-25 10:40:25",`
     `"categories": [],`
     `"tags": [],`
     `"author": {`
       `"id": 1,`
       `"slug": "admin",`
        `"name": "admin",`
       `"first_name": "",`
        `"last_name": "",`
        `"nickname": "admin",`
       `"url": "",`
       `"description": ""`
     `},`
     `"comments": [],`
     `"attachments": [],`
     `"comment_count": 0,`
     `"comment_status": "open"`
   `}`

so basically instead of giving me "status" as an key and "ok" as a value, i get "s" as an object with an index 0 that has a value of "s" for every single character in the json object. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI - when you want to show code fragments like that JSON stuff, paste it into the edit box, select it, then click the "{}" widget above the edit box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `dataType:json` in your $.ajax() request so that jQuery converts the JSON-formatted string into a JavaScript object for you to process as such. You're currently using `application/json` which is a mime type, and not a valid value for this field in a jQuery request.

Comment: thanks a lot I must have left it in there after failing at a previous method of getting the json information to load :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can even try data = eval(data) , this javascript statement should convert your string to json object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jquery function:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

before using $.each.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it in my AngularJS app is by sending the response from the server (I'm using Node Express) as a JavaScript object, rather than as a string. Nothing else worked for me.

```
var response = {};
response.error = "Error message";
res.send(response);
```