# Angular 1.x: $resource JSON is returning as a weird object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, angular-resource

I have been working with `$resource` for a little bit now, however it seems tricky to use with `JSON` return values. I have tried many solutions but it seems to always return it as an object with..less than desirable output as shown in the image below.

[image]

When I verify the data is postman I receive something like this:

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "text": "their pet cat"
    }
   ],
  ...
```

With this I know the data is being sent properly. However, every solution I try for getting the data back correctly using `$resource` gives me the weird object you saw in the image above.

I have tried many but I believe these are closest:

Attempt One:

```
jsonpquery: { method: 'JSONP', params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, isArray: true }
```

Attempt Two

```
return $resource('myBackend.php?action=word',
  {}, {
  query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
});
```

Attempt 3:

```
return $resource('myBackend.php?action=word',
  { get: { method: "JSON", isArray: false}});
```

This is in a factory and I call it like so:

```
dictionaryFactory.getWord('cat')
  .query().$promise.then(function(value) {
    console.log('value value', typeof value);
    console.log('value value',  value);
});
```

I am fairly sure I am not setting up my `$resource` return function correctly
but after a few days of searching and trying solutions on the web I assume I am not understanding how to do it.

I have tried the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855583/json-returns-every-character-as-a-separate-object) and was unable to solve the issue. The data comes back the same.

Update: I have now tried this as well:

```
query: {
  method: 'GET',
  isArray: true,
  transformResponse: function(data) {
    return angular.fromJson(data).items;
  }
}
```

However this just gives me the following error in console:

> Unexpected number in JSON at position 7305 at JSON.parse

I know the data is not the problem as I am using the API From Oxford: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/d

Update:

I read some more and tried this however I get am error

> Unexpected number in JSON at position 7305

:

```
return $resource('myBackend.php?action=word', {},
   {
       jsonpquery: {
         method: 'get',
         dataType: 'json',
         transformResponse: function(data, headers){
            return JSON.parse(data);
        }
       }
});
```

I also tried this however for some reason then I get a 403. Which I do not understand as when it is a `get` request it will return the weird object of characters.

```
return $resource('backend.php?action=oxford', {}  {
       jsonpquery: {
         method: 'JSON',
         isArray: true
       }
});
```

Comment: So are you sure it's not coming from the server? Have you also checked to network tab in the developer tools and verified the response is a proper well formatted json?

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I'd suggest to replicate the problem as a plunk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json returns every character as a separate object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855583/json-returns-every-character-as-a-separate-object)

Comment: Do not think it is a duplicate. I tried the answers from that post and they did not change the output of the data I receieved

Comment: The network shows correct response. {
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Oxford University Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "cat",
            "language": "en",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {

Comment: have you ensure if server returned Content-Type: application/json; in response's headers?